# Hierarchy database structure in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am looking to store data in mongodb in a hierarchical manner.
For example 
the Structure should look like below:

```
Database1
    Datastore1
             Collection1
             Collection2
             Collection3
             Collection4

     Datastore2
             Collection1
             Collection2
             Collection3
             Collection4

Database2
    Datastore1
             Collection1
             Collection2
             Collection3
             Collection4
    Datastore2
             Collection1
             Collection2
             Collection3
             Collection4
    Datastore3
             Collection1
             Collection2
             Collection3
             Collection4
    Datastore4
             Collection1
             Collection2
             Collection3
             Collection4

Database3
    Datastore1
             Collection1
             Collection2
             Collection3
             Collection4"
```

is there a way to store data like above in mongoDB? Please help

Comment: could you describe problem that you are going to solve? It looks like the real world behind your structure could be represented in more flexible way.

Answer (score 0):

You can have hierarchical data within the collection. The hierarchical data in a collection is called embedded documents. However, as mentioned in your question, you can't have datastore level. The hierarchy in that structure is database followed by n number of collections. You can have multiple databases and each database can have multiple collections. Each collection can have multiple embedded documents.

Database -> Collections